# Minikube Service Not Reachable From Anywhere

Tags: linux, kubernetes, minikube

So I've read a bunch of these similar questions/issues on stackoverflow and I understand it enough but not sure what I am missing.

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev-namespace
  labels:
    web: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      web: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        web: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    web: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

This is my *minikube ip*:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

This is the service

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
nginx-service   NodePort   10.104.139.228   <none>        80:30360/TCP   14
```

This is the deployment

```
$ kubectl get deployments.apps
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-deployment   2/2     2            2           14h
```

This is the pods

```
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx-deployment-5b78696cc8-9fpmr   1/1     Running   0          14h   172.17.0.6   minikube   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-5b78696cc8-h4m72   1/1     Running   0          14h   172.17.0.4   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

This is the endpoints

```
$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME            ENDPOINTS                         AGE
nginx-service   172.17.0.4:8080,172.17.0.6:8080   14h
```

But when I try to *curl 10.104.139.228:30360* it just hangs. When I try to *curl 192.168.49.2:30360* I get the *Connection refused*

I am sure that using *NodePort* means I need to use the *node* ip and that would be the server's local IP since I am using *minikube* and *control plane* and *worker* are in the same server.

What am I missing here? Please help, this is driving me crazy. I should mention that I am able to *kubectl exec -ti pod-name -- /bin/bash* and if I do a *curl localhost* I do get the famous response "Welcome to NGINX"

Comment: I should mention that my service.yml does have the same namespace but forgot to add it :/

Comment: Can you retry with containerPort set to 80 in deployment and targetPort in service also to 80?

Comment: thanks Aydin, I added my solution at the bottom myself right after creating this issue :/ i guess seeing typing it out aI saw my mistake immediately lol thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind :/ I feel very foolish I see that the mistake was the container ports :/ my *nginx* pods are listening on port 80 not port 8080

For anyone out there, I updated my config files to this:

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: busy-qa
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    web: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: busy-qa
  labels:
    web: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      web: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        web: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

Now when I *curl* I get the NGINX response

```
$ curl 192.168.49.2:31168
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```